# Connecting to Https Server using Boost and OpenSSL

Tags: c++, boost, https

I am connecting to a HTTPS server using BoostAsio library using open SSL. For no reason I am getting build errors. I have 2 files mainly, first being the executor.hpp file that goes as

```
#include "requestCreator.hpp"

class Executor
{
  public :
  Executor(Cli &cli)
  {
    //! Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(svc);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(cli.getIP(), "8080");
    endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
  }

  int connect();
  int write(RequestCreator &requestcreator);

  boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>& getSocket()
  {
    return ssock;
  }

private :
  boost::asio::io_service svc;
  boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(svc, boost::asio::ssl::context::method::sslv23_client);
  boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ssock(svc, ctx);

  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator;
 };
```

and executor.cpp as follows

```
#include "executor.hpp"

int Executor::connect()
{
  boost::system::error_code ec ;
  boost::asio::connect(ssock.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator);

  if (ec)
  {
    ssock.lowest_layer().close();
    svc.stop();
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
 }

 int Executor::write(RequestCreator &requestCreator)
 {
   boost::system::error_code ec ;
   boost::asio::write(ssock, requestCreator.getRequest(), ec);

   if (ec)
   {
     ssock.lowest_layer().close();
     svc.stop();
     return 0;
  }
  return 1;
 }
```

Consider `cli.getIP()` and `requestCreator.getRequest()` as method with return types as string and `boost::asio::streambuf&` respectively

What am I missing in this code ?

Comment: I can share the error log if needed

Comment: here is a library built on top of boost.asio that has https client example: https://github.com/vinniefalco/Beast

Comment: @Evgeniy I need HTTPS Connection